# Best practice for showing multiple websites

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am super new to Web-developing but have to build a WebApp in which the user is supposed to:

1. Select a Item
2. Get a list of Items dependent on the fist selection and do stuff with this List
3. Get Information dependent on the first and second selection

Each of these steps is currently developed in a seperate html/php file.

I am looking for a good way to connect these pages with each other without data loss. And honestly I have no Idea how to achieve this.

I don't want finished code. I want ideas and hints on how to solve this, because I would like to learn something.

Comment: wow what a breath of fresh air (i don't want finished code. lmao :D), but anyways if you want the data to persist but doesn't necessarily mean not refresh the page, you could use php sessions, if you want more sophistication, you'll need to incorporate xmlhttprequest, more learning curve yes but it would look seamless

Comment: how about using a framework like React and then you could add some state management and pass the state down as props to trigger new changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have 2 options here.
First you could simply do a HTML form with a GET method that would lead to another page, where you would display another form with list of items you need. You can get the first selected item from `$_GET`.

The other solution would simply be to use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp), which would be more convenient. After the user selects the first item, you send AJAX request to a PHP file, get the list of items, and display them.